# Disabling voice commands in Dragon NaturallySpeaking 15

Tags: dragon-naturally-speaking

Is there a way to (preferably permanently) disable all voice commands in Dragon NaturallySpeaking 15 (so that all voice input is interpreted as text)? There was a menu option in an earlier version, but the new version has the menus completely rearranged, you can no longer access anything from the system tray icon, and the settings menu accessible from DragonBar, does not seem to contain an option for disabling voice commands.

This is what the DragonBar looks like in the new version. Weirdly, I think a larger version of the DragonBar flickered into existence for a moment on program startup, but disappeared before I could really make it out, and I cannot find any way to bring it back.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember when I tried NaturallySpeaking (it look different so I assume it's a [different version](https://www.nuance.com/dragon.html) - check "products" in the menue) you need to choose the recognition mode `Dictation`. This disabled the commands in my case.

I'm not sure about you're version, but it seems you need to expand the toolbar / disable the Auto-collapse (Note: there is also an option to change the mode directly without expanding it and one for the Classic DragonBar, maybe that gives you the "old" layout I was using).

[image]

In the new DragonBar you should see a drop down box below `Now listening for...` where you can select the recognition mode (Dictation, Dictation and Command, etc.). [Here](https://www.nuance.com/products/help/dragon/dragon-for-pc/enx/professionalgroup/main/Content/DragonBar/dragonbar.htm) and [here](https://www.nuance.com/products/help/dragon/dragon-for-pc/enx/professionalgroup/main/Content/DragonBar/dragonbar_working_with.htm) is an overview.

[image]

In my version you had to select the `modes` on the toolbar and then `Dictation`. Here's a link to the [menu items tutorial](http://dragoncontent.nuance.com/training/dns-training/enx/scx/professional/getstarted/menus.htm) although it's explained rather briefly.

[image]

If it doesn't work, as a temp. ad-hoc work around (until you find a permanent solution - hope it still works): you should also be able to avoid commands by using the shift key while you speak. As it is explained [here](http://dragoncontent.nuance.com/training/dns-training/enx/scx/professional/dictation/commands.htm).

**Update:**
That is what my Option-Appearance Screen looked like. If you go through Tools-Options and click on appearance (it's the same one that is used in the [user guide, the dragon professional workbook](https://www.nuance.com/content/dam/nuance/en_us/collateral/dragon/guide/gd-dragon-professional-workbook-en-us.pdf) on page 27):
[image]

Comment: To whom ever down voted or is going to down vote, please consider sharing you're knowledge leaving a small note why (in your view) this is not an acceptable answer or what would be necessary to improve the answer. Thanks!

Comment: @rwallace I updated my answer, let me know if it works

Comment: So I was not hallucinating the existence of the larger DragonBar! But it still only gives me the small one that does not have the useful options. I have turned off auto collapse and restarted, and it still only gives me the small one, and the small one does not give me that menu you show with the option for Classic DragonBar. How did you get the small one to give you that menu?

Comment: @rwallace I don't have the software any more, so I can't replicate it at the moment. How did you turn of auto collapse? Please post a screenshot of the option to turn it of. Also post a screenshot of the bar after you turned it of. And you don't have to get the classic bar in order to change the mode.

Comment: Bounty awarded, and thanks for the help so far! Posted screenshot of the option to turn off autocollapse, to go with the existing screenshot of the bar as it is now that I have turned it off (which is the same as it was with autocollapse turned on and the bar manually opened).

Comment: @rwallace thank! : ) how did you get that window? did you click on settings?

Comment: did you click on settings? -  Yes.

Comment: @rwallace that's all strange... the appearance tab should have more settings. I wonder if there is an expert mode or s.th. in order to get them all (or if you have a limited, different or newer version). Do you get the option window as well if you click on Tools->Options? Do you get a context menu if you right click the dragon bar? I posted a screenshot of how my window looked like.

Comment: @rwallace that's all strange... the appearance tab should have more settings. I wonder if there is an expert mode or s.th. in order to get them all (or if you have a limited, different or older/newer version, do you use Dragon Professional Individual 15?). Do you get the option window as well if you click on Tools->Options? Do you get a context menu if you right click the dragon bar? I posted a screenshot of how my window looked like.

Comment: Ah! I think that's it - I have the home version, it didn't say anything about only the professional version allowing disabling of this crap. Okay, thanks!

Comment: @rwallace sure thing, there is a overview of the different features [here](https://www.nuance.com/content/dam/nuance/en_us/collateral/dragon/feature-matrix/fm-dragon-naturally-speaking-en-us.pdf) If you like you can send me a screenshot of the other menues, maybe I'll still be able to help you there.